React custom component library using rollup doesn't work with scss
Currently, I am trying to make some custom React component library using Rollup. But I want to use SCSS. While using SCSS, it works fine in Storybook. When I publish it to npm and use it in a Next.js project, CSS doesn't come out.
I used the rollup-plugin-scss for SCSS bundling.
rollup.config.js
package.json
folder structure
